# php-sql groups data with the same category

Tags: php, sql, categories

How can I print my fetch rows into groups of data?
For example i have these on my database

```
title       category
one         number
two         number
three       number
a           letter
b           letter
c           letter
```

and I wanted to print it out on a different table.

```
table1      table2
number      letter
one         a
two         b
three       c
```

here's what I've tried.

```
$select = "SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `category`";
$result = mysql_query($select);

$current_cat = null;

while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    { 
        if ($rows["category"] != $current_cat) 
                    {
                        $current_cat = $rows["category"];
                        echo "<p>$current_cat</p>";
                    }
        echo"$rows[title]";
}
```

the output of these codes is like this

```
number  
one
two
three

letter
a
b
c
```

but then again, I wanted it to be in separate table.

Comment: Will there by only two categories always?

Comment: no, I just post two for simplicity

Comment: So for each category, you want it in a separate table?

Comment: Yup.. 
because at the later i wanted them to fit on whole page. like adding <div float:left>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add an if statement to test if the $current_cat is equal to the previous loops $current_cat. Do so by adding a new variable $last_cat, setting it equal to the current iterations $current_cat at the end of the while loop. Here is an example

```
   $select = "SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `category`";
    $result = mysql_query($select);

    $current_cat = null;
    $last_cat = null;

    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 

            if ($current_cat == null) {
        // Create a table with an id name of the first table
        echo "<table id='" . $rows["category"] . "'>";
// Write the first row of the table - Category Title
echo "<tr class='categoryTitle'><td>" . $rows["category"] . "</td></tr>";
        }

    // Set the $current_cat to current loop category value
         $current_cat = $rows["category"];

    if ($last_cat != null) {
            if ($current_cat != $last_cat) {
            // Close table from previous $current_cat
        echo "</table>";
        // Create new table with id name of the category
        echo "<table id='" . $rows["category"] . "'>";
// Write the first row of the table - Category Title
echo "<tr class='categoryTitle'><td>" . $rows["category"] . "</td></tr>";
        }
    }

                            }
// Write new row in table with the value of the title
                echo "<tr><td>" . $rows[title] . "</td></tr>";

    // set the $last_cat to the value of $current_cat at the end of the loop
    $last_cat = $current_cat;
    } 

    // Close the last table after while loop ends
    echo "</table>";
```

This will allow you to create separate tables based on the category name no matter how many categories you have and allow you to style the tables based on the category name.

Comment: thank you so much @Matt , thank you for giving me your time, I appreciate it a lot. btw, there is just one error.                      
echo "<tr class="categoryTitle"><td>$current_cat</td></tr>";
must be echo "<tr class="categoryTitle"><td>$rows[category]</td></tr>";

Comment: why did you put an id for table, I'm just curious :)

Comment: I put the id in the table so that you can control its styling through CSS. This will also allow you to use JavaScript by calling each table independently... Good for highlighting effects or on click actions. It isn't required to make the code work, however, it will make the life of other developers on your team easier if you are only working on the PHP.

Comment: what do you call a form with an editor on it, like this one http://i45.tinypic.com/124bguu.png . Sorry if I have to ask it here. I cant find the right keywords to google it.

Comment: The html tag is known as a "<textarea>". However, the one that you took a screenshot of is a more than just a text area. This screenshot is essential a small program, like Microsoft Word, that allows the user to format the text to their preference. Luckily, there is a free plugin that allows the developer to pick what formatting tools the user gets. I've only worked with this feature once but it works effectively. Essentially, the app writes inline html/css for styling. TinyMCE - http://www.tinymce.com/